# change the shape of a mux with selection

Tags: circuitikz

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, chains, decorations.markings,intersections,calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[scale=0.4] 
                (90,3)coordinate (O)
            --++(30:1)coordinate (A)
            --++(90:4)coordinate (B)
            --++(150:1) coordinate (C)
            --cycle;
        \draw ($(A)!0.5!(B)$)--++(0:1)node[right]{$F$};

    \draw ($(O)!0.7!(A)$)--++(-90:1)--++(180:2)node[left]{$b$};

    \draw ($(O)!0.3!(A)$)--++(-90:0.5)--++(180:1.75)node[left]{$a$};

    \foreach \y/\t in {0.1/1,0.2/2,0.3/3,0.4/4} {
    \draw ($(C)! \y*2 !(O)$)--++(180:1) node[left] {$IN \t$};}      

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

1. How can I have inputs of the mux starting from 0 (IN0,IN1..IN3) instead of (IN1..IN4)?
2. Also move the selection pins in the upper part of the mux (I tried with xscale = -2, but it is not the desired output)
3. Get the coordinates for IN1--IN4 and a,b

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. The code given is naming the input terminal using a forloop. Where the variable `\t` is varied as 1,2,3,4. All you have to do is to change this to 0,1,2,3.
2. The select lines are drawn from the lower edge (`(O)`to`(A)`) of multiplexer. change it to top edge (`(B)` to `(C)`).
3. You can use `coordinate` to name the coordinates.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[scale=0.4] 
         (90,3)coordinate (O)
        --++(30:1)coordinate (A) % lower edge
        --++(90:4)coordinate (B) % right edge
        --++(150:1) coordinate (C) % top edge
        --cycle; % left edge

\draw ($(A)!0.5!(B)$)--++(0:1)node[right]{$F$};
\draw ($(B)!0.7!(C)$)|-++(-2,0.5)coordinate (b) node[left]{$b$};
\draw ($(B)!0.3!(C)$)|-($(b.east)+(0,0.5)$)coordinate (a) node[left]{$a$};

\foreach \y/\t in {0.1/0,0.2/1,0.3/2,0.4/3} {
\draw ($(C)! \y*2 !(O)$)--++(180:1) coordinate (in\t) node[left]  {$IN \t$};} 

\draw[red] (a) -- (b);
\draw[red] (in0) -- (in1) -- (in2) -- (in3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can the inputs have coordinates so that circuitz elements can connect to them ? Can I mix this drawing in a circuitz diagram?